# How to pass drag interactions through an overlay composable, but capture tap interactions in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-pager

I have a hierarchy of two views laid on top of each other. The bottom one is a HorizontalPager, and the top one is an overlay. The overlay is transparent, but has a logic where it shows information when user taps the overlay.

In (pseudo-ish) code, it looks like this:

```
Box {
    // The pager that should be draggable
    HorizontalPager(...) {
        ...
    }

    // The overlay that should be tappable
    PagerOverlay(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that the overlay does not pass drag events to the pager. How do I achieve that?